# CSS Grid with 3D perspective as image overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I need to have a soccer field on which I can place players via drag and drop. I defined 11 droppable areas via a bootstrap grid so that every player has a predefined zone where he can be dropped.
the `.field` has the attachment image as background.

[image]

```
<div class="field">
<div class="row" style="height: 25%">
<div class="col-xs-12">goalie</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="height: 25%">
<div class="col-xs-4">defender</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">defender</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">defender</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="height: 25%">
<div class="col-xs-3">midfielder</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">midfielder</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">midfielder</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">midfielder</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="height: 25%">
<div class="col-xs-4">striker</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">striker</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">striker</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything is just like I want, but my grid should now match the background image, which has a nice 3D-perspective.

How can I create a perspective that matches my background-image perfectly? To be precise: The top left corner of my grid should match the top left corner of the playing field in the backgrgound, the top right corner of the grid should match the top right corner of the background and so on..

Can I do this via CSS or does my image have to be an SVG so I can precisely get the desired points?

Comment: I think a simple but effective way of doing this is by changing the size of a player depending on where it is on the Y-axis for example, if a player is at the bottom of the screen it's 100px high, if it's at the top it's 33xp high and if it's at the center it's 66px high

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know how to achieve this exact match with a HTML grid like the one you have... 
If you want a grid of DIV's your best bet would be to override the row width to have the grid cells all be inside the fields lines.

If you want to have it match the image EXACTLY, I would refer to javascript. 
Customize the drag and drop area and calculate in what section of the field your players are.

And when you're at it, you can use the Y axis to determine how far back your players are positioned, and adjust their size to match the perspective and create the illusion that they are further away.